# The polynomial P(x) is equal to $(i + x)^{2024}$. Let $S$ be the sum of all the real coefficients of $P(x)$. Find $\log_{2} S$.

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, binomial-coefficients

I think the answer to this problem is $1012$, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas? Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite straight forward: $S=\mathrm{Re} P(1)=2^{1012}$, so $\log_2 S=1012$.